# Separate unified words in strings using Python

Tags: python, text, nlp

I have some texts and some words are stuck together. The text is in Spanish. For example, "Hola cómoestás yobien y tú" should be "Hola cómo estás yo bien y tú".
Is there any Python library with which I could separate the words? I only find help online regarding string splitting and tokenization but nothing on how to separate concatenated words. Thank you